# Unable to calculate the frequency of unique values in a columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, import-from-excel

I am working on a project that requires me to calculate the Number of time a student was present and the number of times he was absent in the classes of different subject and calculate the percentage of his attendance. I have his attendance record as follows

```
    Attend  Date    Subject
96  Present 09-04-2020  AM-II
69  Present 16-04-2020  AM-II
61  Present 20-04-2020  AM-II
49  Present 22-04-2020  AM-II
45  Present 23-04-2020  AM-II
... ... ... ...
14  Present 12-04-2020  LMS
13  Absent  18-04-2020  LMS
11  Absent  19-04-2020  LMS
10  Present 25-04-2020  LMS
9   Present 26-04-2020  LMS
```

I am using pandas library of python to calculate the number of time "Present" and the number of times "Absent" appears for each unique subject but I am unable to do so. Here is what I am doing.

```
data=pd.read_csv("data1.csv") 
  
#sorting data frame by Team and then By names 
data.sort_values(["Subject", "Date"], axis=0, 
                 ascending=True, inplace=True) 
p = 0
a = 0
total = 0
attpercent = {}
data.set_index(["Subject"], inplace = True, 
                            append = True, drop = False)
temp = ""
data = data.infer_objects()
for Subject, Attend in data.iterrows()
    if(temp == ""):
        temp = Subject
        if Attend == "Present":
                p = p + 1
        else:
            a = a + 1
    else:
        if(temp == Subject):
            if Attend == "Present":
                p = p + 1
            else:
                a = a + 1
        else:
            total = a + p
            attpercent[temp] = (p * 100) / total
            a = 0
            p = 0
            temp = Subject 
            if Attend == "Present":
                p = p + 1
            else:
                a = a + 1
                
print(attpercent)
```

It shows an error :

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-9d7243427e5f> in <module>
     18 data = data.infer_objects()
     19 for Subject, Attend in data.iterrows():
---> 20     Attend = str(Attend)
     21     if(temp == ""):
     22         temp = Subject

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

I am using pandas for the first time and so I don't know much about it. I tried to convert the type of columns using `infer_objects` and `astypes()` but still I get the same error. Please help.

Comment: Iterrows() don't return columns it will return row, you should use `for index, row in data.iterrow()` tehn you can access the column value by `row[Attend]` and `row['Subject']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to avoid for loops and iteration as much as possible and get familiar with `pandas` methods like `.groupby`, `.pivot_table` and `.unstack`. For this particular problem, you can use `.groupby` with `.size` and then `.unstack` to move rows to columns and get the data in a nice format in preparation of calculating the attendance rate.

```
df = df.groupby(['Subject','Attend']).size().reset_index() \
       .set_index(['Subject', 'Attend']) \
       .unstack(1).fillna(0).astype(int)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df['Attendance'] = df['Present'] / ( df['Present'] + df['Absent'])
df
```

output:

```
Attend  Absent  Present Attendance
Subject         
AM-II   0       5       1.0
LMS     2       3       0.6
```

More detailed explanation.

After the `.groupby` on the relevant columns and `size` to count the occurrences, with `.set_index(['Subject', 'Attend'])`, I am setting these two column on the index in preparation for the next step. Next, I move `Attend` to the headers to put this dataset in a nice matrix format like and Excel Pivot Table. With `.unstack(1)`, I'm taking the second index column that I just set (remember python starts at `0`, so `1` takes the second index column and makes them my headers now, essentially reshaping the dataframe from rows to columns in a very convenient way. If I did `.unstack(0)`, it would have moved `Subject` to the headers, which wouldn't have visualized the data in the way we wanted.

Finally, `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)` removes a level from the Multiindex to make it look cleaner, and then the `Attendance` calculation is pretty straightforward, which divides # of Present by Total to get the attendance rate per subject.

---

Let's say, the full data included another column for student. Based off the first example, you could probably try from here to figure out how to do that, but this is what you could do.

input:

```
    Attend  Date       Subject  Student
96  Present 09-04-2020  AM-II   Kathy
69  Present 16-04-2020  AM-II   John
61  Present 20-04-2020  AM-II   John
49  Present 22-04-2020  AM-II   John
45  Present 23-04-2020  AM-II   Kathy
14  Present 12-04-2020  LMS     Kathy
13  Absent  18-04-2020  LMS     Kathy
11  Absent  19-04-2020  LMS     John
10  Present 25-04-2020  LMS     Kathy
9   Present 26-04-2020  LMS     John
```

code:

```
df = df.groupby(['Student','Subject','Attend']).size().reset_index().set_index(['Student','Subject', 'Attend']).unstack(2).fillna(0).astype(int)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df['Attendance'] = df['Present'] / ( df['Present'] + df['Absent'])
df

        Attend  Absent  Present Attendance
Student Subject         
John    AM-II   0       3       1.000000
        LMS     1       1       0.500000
Kathy   AM-II   0       2       1.000000
        LMS     1       2       0.666667
```

The code is almost the same. You just include the extra column `Student` with `.groupby` and `.set_index()` and increase `.unstack` fom `1` to `2`, since the `Attend` column is now the third `index` column as specified with `.set_index()`. Then, change `drop_level(1)` to `drop_level(0)`, since you have two columns on the index.

Finally, if you would like a clean dataset with no multiindex, simply do `df = df.reset_index()` as a final step to return:

```
Attend  Student Subject Absent  Present Attendance
0       John    AM-II   0       3       1.000000
1       John    LMS     1       1       0.500000
2       Kathy   AM-II   0       2       1.000000
3       Kathy   LMS     1       2       0.666667
```

Comment: Thanks for such an explainatory answer. However I can't understand why is the 'Date' column not being displayed ? When I tried to put it in the groupby() , the df['Attendance'] won't show the correct answer since it would show attendence % for each day. If suppose I want to calculate % of attendance after a pirticular date how can I do that ?

Comment: @YashSethia , ‘Date’ is not included in the groupby, so it is not included in the final result, but you are correct that you wouldn’t want to groupby date anyway. To filter after a specific date do ‘ df.loc[df[‘Date’] > ‘09-04-2020’.groupby’.... You can replace ‘09-04-2020’ with any date. Hope this helps. Please upvote and accept if helpful.

Comment: I tried writing this '   
data = data.loc[data["Date"] > "01-05-2020"].groupby(['Subject', 'Attend']).size().reset_index() \
       .set_index(['Subject','Attend']) \
        .unstack(1).fillna(0).astype(int)      ' But it isn't working. I am still getting the % for all the dates

Comment: @YashSerthia Before the groupby try data[‘Date’] = pd.to_datetime(data[‘Date’],dayfirst=True) ... and then try ... data = data.loc[data["Date"] > "2020-05-01"] If you get an error, then please post it.

Comment: I did 

data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], dayfirst = True)
data = data.loc[data['Date'] > "01-05-2020"]

But nothing happened. The output is still for the entire data.

Comment: Change “01-05-2020” to “2020-05-01”. That is the universal dale format in python “yyyy-mm-dd”

Comment: I changed the read.csv() as
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Sarthak_project\attendance\attendance\final.csv", parse_dates= [1])

And made the following changes in to code, but it is not working properly.
date = datetime(2020, 7, 25)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
data = data.loc[data["Date"] > date].groupby(['Subject', 'Attend']).size().reset_index() \
    .set_index(['Subject','Attend']) \
    .unstack(1).fillna(0).astype(int)

This should give 0 in all fields but the output shows around 20 entries.